# How to call an API on an interval in Superblocks

Tags: superblock

I tried [Superblocks](https://docs.superblocks.com/components/grids), and wanted to call an API for a Grid Component on an interval. My Grid component pulls data from a Google Sheet and I wanted it to update every `2 seconds`, but wasn't able to find an auto-refresh functionality to poll the API trigger on the interval. Is there a way to do this in Superblocks?

Answer (score 0):

In Superblocks you can use [Timers](https://docs.superblocks.com/build-applications/live-update-queries-and-components-with-timers) to call actions on a pre-defined interval.

In this case, you can create a **Timer**, set the desired interval in milliseconds, choose `Run APIs` as the **Action Type**, and pick the API that polls the data from your Google Sheet from the dropdown.

The Trigger then calls your API on the specified interval and auto-refreshes your [Grid Component](https://docs.superblocks.com/applications/components-library/grid) with the updated data.